# How to change the color of an icon when radio input is selected?

Tags: reactjs

I've had a problem for several hours, I've created two buttons that are connected to radio inputs.

I use styled components, and I would like to have the possibility that my check icons will be colored white when the user selects the option.

I was thinking of using a state but I don't know if it's the right solution.

```
import { React, useState } from "react";
import fire from '../firebase/firebase';
import styled from "styled-components";
import { FaCheckCircle } from 'react-icons/fa';
import '../../App.css';

export const BoxContainer = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
  
`;

export const Gauche = styled.div`
 
  
`;

export const Droite = styled.div`
 
  
`;

export const Descriptif = styled.div`
    background-color: #F9F9FB;
    margin: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 500px;
  
`;

export const Option = styled.div`
    background-color: #8064F7;
    margin: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    width:500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  
`;

export const Optionbutton = styled.input`
 visibility: hidden;


 
`;

export const Select = styled.div`
   margin-left: 30px;

   ${Optionbutton}:checked {
       color:red !important;
   }
`;

export const Intitule = styled.div`
   text-align:left;
   font-weight:bold;
   color:white;
   font-size: 20px;
   
`;

export const MiddleBox = styled.div`
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-left: 60px;
   
`;

export const Economie = styled.div`
   background-color:#6D43E5;
   border-radius:20px;
   padding: 5px;
   color:white;
`;

export const Prix = styled.div`
   color:white;
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:25px;
   margin-right: 20px;
`;

export const OptionLabel = styled.label`
 cursor: pointer;
`;




export function Shop(props) { 

    const [radio,setRadio] = useState("option1");
    

    console.log({radio});

    return (
        <BoxContainer>
            <Gauche>
                <Descriptif>Bonjour</Descriptif>
            </Gauche>
            <Droite><form>
            <OptionLabel><Optionbutton thechecked={props.isSelected}  type="radio" value="option1" checked={radio === "option1"} onChange={(e) =>{ setRadio(e.target.value)}}></Optionbutton>
            
            
            <Option>
                    <Select  ><FaCheckCircle   /></Select>
                    <MiddleBox>
                        
                        
                        <Intitule>1 Ticket vidéo</Intitule>
                    </MiddleBox>
                    <Prix>29.99 €</Prix>
                </Option>
            
            
            
            </OptionLabel>

            <OptionLabel><Optionbutton  type="radio" value="option2" checked={radio === "option2"} onChange={(e) =>{ setRadio(e.target.value)}}></Optionbutton>
            
            
            <Option>
                    <Select><FaCheckCircle/></Select>
                    <MiddleBox>
                        
                        
                        <Intitule>1 Ticket vidéo</Intitule>
                    </MiddleBox>
                    <Prix>29.99 €</Prix>
                </Option>
            
            
            
            </OptionLabel></form>
            </Droite>
        </BoxContainer>
    )
}

export default Shop;
```

[image: Input buttons]

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In styled-components you can pass props to created components, so you can pass true value to your Select component for change color. To use prop inside styled-component try this:

```
export const Select = styled.div`
   margin-left: 30px;
   color: ${({isSelected}) => isSelected ? "red" : "black"};
`;
```

And in JSX you should do something like this:

```
<Select isSelected={radio === "option1"}>
   <FaCheckCircle />
</Select>
```